# CSS Unwanted whitespace added after anchor tag

Tags: html, css, anchor, whitespace

Whitespace is added AFTER anchor tags and I don't know why. I've read that this can be used caused by percentage width values but I don't use any for the div element in question. Can't it be caused by the elements parent style?

[image: Whitespace error]
<sub>(source: [imageupper.com](http://imageupper.com/s02/1/2/B13890541672052617_1.png))</sub>

Note the whitespace after the "Events" link. This happens on every anchor tag on my site.

Any ideas o how to resolve it would be appreciated.

HTML

```
<a href="/events/">Events</a>
```

CSS

```
a {
    color:#000;
    text-decoration:underline;
}
a:hover {
    color:#000;
    background:#ff6600;
    text-decoration:none;
}
#content {
    width:800px;
    margin:0 auto;
    padding:15px 10px 10px 15px;
}
```

Without adding my entire site's code; the above code is the best that I can offer. Although, I'm certain that that particular code is not the culprit.

When I copy and paste the last few words into a text editor; only one space appears, as it should do.

Comment: Can you add your html and css? may be to jsfiddle?

Comment: You should show us your HTML and CSS, in your post, as well as in a [jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/) or something similar. Not providing this is asking us to help while blindfolded.

Comment: There could be any number of culprits. You will need to provide a relevant code snippet, for people to pinpoint the exact cause.

Comment: I agree, we need to see your code JustSomeGuy

Comment: Erm, if you're certain that particular code is not the culprit, then that won't help us diagnose the problem, will it? You need to provide the code that recreates the problem.

Comment: Use a tool like firebug for firefox to investigate further. This will help determine the nature of the space, be it padding, margins, additional space etc. You can inspect the element and get a break -down of the classes and styles applied to it. Hitting f12 in chrome provides similar functionality.

Comment: setek - If I knew which part of my code was causing the problem then I wouldn't need your help. Short of showing you my entire stylesheet then I can't really show you any code.

Comment: Then you won't get any definitive answers, only speculation.

Comment: setek - Well, speculation is better than what I have at the minute so I'm good with it.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Could this be the dreaded [Inline-block Whitespace Problem](http://css-tricks.com/fighting-the-space-between-inline-block-elements)?

Check your style sheets for something like this:

```
a {
  inline-block;
}
```

OR

```
.example {
  display: inline-block;
}
```

If you find that, try removing or changing the display type.

Answer (score 0):

1) Check your CSS. Somewhere inside:

```
a:link { ... }
a:visited { ... }
a:hover { ... }
a:active { ... }
```

OR

```
a.someClassName {
  padding-right: 16px;
  background: url(pix/ext_link_14x14.png) no-repeat right;
}
```

there could be

```
padding-right: 16px;
```

or something similar.

Check all of the style sheets included for this page.
Another style sheet can override the one that you have provided.

2) Try to make some "debugging". For example, use Firebug Add-on for Firefox, go to HTML tab and move your mouse over that tag (in the code part). It will be highlighted (on the page) with different colors depending on, if that was a margin, padding, etc. I just move my mouse over code and it highlights the tag with spaces around it with different colors. This can help to get the idea of what keyword to find in the style sheet.

3) Try to disable all inherited css stylesheets for the "a" tag.
For example, place this piece of code to your html page:

```
<style type="text/css">
a {
  padding: 0px;
  margin: 0px;
}
</style>
```

4) If you use DHTML, JavaScript, jQuery onload event - disable it temporarily. If the spaces are back to normal, then we know exactly that the problem is within JavaScript scope. Debug JavaScript step by step to find the exact place where the padding (or some other property) is set to the "a" tag.

Comment: With the exception of a jQuery library stylesheet, I only have one stylesheet in use across my entire site and jQuery stylesheets have never interfered with my CSS before.

Comment: @JustSomeGuy How have you attempted to debug this?  Most modern browsers have a css debugger.

Answer (score 0):

Please add below some styling in anchor tag
`style="display:inline-block; text-align:justify; text-wrap:nowrap; word-wrap:break-word;"`

Comment: But I dont recommend this approach. Something strange happens with topicstarter's anchor. We need more info about original CSS. In normal case anchors dont require `style="..."` approach at all.